# How can I edit the html file from a project in three.js editor and continue using it?

Tags: three.js

I wanted to import the script to be able to control the camera as the link: [Orbital Controls exemple](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html), but I'm using the editor so I only have access to HTML when i publish the project.
there is any way to edit the HTML and continue using the editor?

Comment: What editor are you using? Are you using the github editor?

Comment: yes, i dowloaded the source code, but i can't find a way to edit the html and go back to the editor